# I am trying to rotate the image, however the image is rotating at a pivot point

Tags: javascript, html, svg, rotation, element

I want the image to rotate when I click. The image is supposed to rotate 90 degrees clockwise. However, the pivot point is currently located within the center of the element when I would like it to rotate at the  upper right corner of the grey rectangle. any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var htmlNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
function createShape() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var outer = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
  container.append(outer);
  outer.id = "outer"
  console.log(outer.id)
  outer.style.background = "grey";
  outer.style.height = "100px";
  outer.style.width = "150px";
  outer.style.left = "150px";
  outer.style.top = "200px";
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  var shape1 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
  outer.append(shape1);
  shape1.style.width = "100%";
  shape1.style.height = "50%";
  shape1.style.fill = "orange";
  var shape2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
  outer.append(shape2);
  shape2.style.width = "33.33%";
  shape2.style.height = "100%";
  shape2.style.fill = "orange";
}
window.onload = createShape;
window.onclick = rotate;
function rotate() {
  var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
  console.log(outer.style.background)
  outer.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
}
```

```css
.grid {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,transparent 49px,#88F 49px,#88F 50px),
                    repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,transparent,transparent 49px,#88F 49px,#88F 50px);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    top: 8px;
    height: 651px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 501px;
}
#left {
    top: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
}
#right {
    left: 250px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test2)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" onclick= "rotate()" style= "height: 650px; width: 500px; background: black; position: relative">
      <div id= "left" onclick= "moveLeft()"></div>
      <div id= "right" onclick= "moveRight()"></div>
    </div>
    <div class= "grid"></div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the transform-origin CSS property!

For Javascript: [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transformorigin.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

For CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

You can apply something like this to the `outer` element like this:

```js
outer.style.transformOrigin = "left top";
```

Just put this in the `createShape()` function with the rest of the styling

I also recommend you do your styling in CSS, not in Javascript every time you create the element

Comment: i tried adding the the out.style.trsnformOrigin = " left top"; however it did not work as intended. it only moved the element a few squares to the left and a few squares down.

Comment: It works for me as I intended, I don't know if this is what you wanted though

Comment: my apologies, yes this does work, however why does it stop after only one click. i need it to continue to rotate with each click.

Comment: Because each time all you're doing is setting the rotation to 90degrees, not increasing it beyond that!

Comment: To do that you need to remember the orientation of the shape, then use that to set the rotation to the right amount. Maybe you can have an array of instances of an object constructed by calling the `new` operator on a function for each shape. In each object you can store the position and orientation of the shape, and also  what type of shape it is and the the elements themselves. Maybe have a separate array for the shapes that are no longer active and can no longer move anymore. Then put the active one in it's own variable.

Comment: (I'm assuming you want to make something like tetris here) At the start, you create a shape with the function, you pass it the type of shape, and it'll return an object with the properties of the shape and the newly created element. You put that object into a variable for the active shape, and you make functions for moving and rotating the active shape. Then when it hits the bottom, you put the variable in an array for innactive shapes, or discard it all together. Then you create a new shape the same way you did with the last one.

Comment: Also you have to do some wizardry to detect whether the shape can fit with the other shapes. Maybe store that inactive shapes as which individual squares are taken up instead, that'll make things much easier.

Comment: thanks so much, that makes perfect sense about  each time resetting to 90 degrees.
                                                    
var x = 0;
x += 90;
outer.style.transform = "rotate(" + x + "deg)"
```

Comment: and yes i am making tetris, i am just testing out my mechanics with smaller files before  i implement them into my main file. i now have it set up to randomly generate a shape from 5, it drops down one cell every second, left clicking on the right side of the screen moves the shape to the left and a left click on the left side of the screen moves the shape left, right click on the left side of the screen rotates 90deg to the right and right click on the left side of the screen rotates 90deg to the right.

Comment: but i like your idea of an array with disabled shapes and one of enabled shapes. that way whenever they hit the bottom, it can disable the function

Answer (score 1):

Set a transform origin through CSS on the element you're rotating.

For example,

```
transform-origin: top left;
```

See more docs here too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin